# CMS citations: complete page numbers for serialized works

Tags: citation-style

When citing a novel that was originally serialized in a journal (Dickens, for instance), one usually does not give complete pagination of all installments individually. But the issue may arise, if for instance a major focus of analysis is the journal and its handling of, advertising for, and conversations with the author. The issue is particularly significant when citing novels in Japanese literary journals, for instance, wherein each installment may be a quite small fraction of the page range of the complete volume; to skip the page numbers in the citation would thus be like citing an article in a large scientific journal volume without giving page numbers. How would one give such pagination?

EXAMPLE (note form):
Charles Dickens, *Oliver Twist; or, the Parish Boy's Progress*, in *Bentley's Miscellany* (February 1837--April 1839), PAGES.

Comment: One might have a note at the end (appendix) with all of the issues and pages for the entire novel, but in your analysis you would be referring to specific somethings about a specific bit.

Comment: @JonCuster Usually, yes, but not necessarily. I'm working on a volume discussing a lot of novellas, most of them serialized over 2-14 months in huge monthly volumes that include, along with lots of other articles, 3-5 running serial works at a time. Often authors make slight changes between original versions and 1-volume reprints. If someone wants to follow up a remark that chapter 13 changed dramatically, they need the page run of the original chapter 13 in part 7 of the original periodical publication.

Comment: Right, understood. So, at some point in the work you have a listing of every single issue and pages for the convenience of readers interested in finding it all again. When discussing how chapter 13 changed you reference the specific issue/pages. (It would not surprise me if at least one novel ended up changing where installments got published as well).

Comment: Something I've done in some personal bibliographic lists (not for publication) is to use something like "(February 1837 & April 1837 & November 1837 & January 1838 & March 1838), pp. 28-36 & 30-37 & 17-26 & 48-59 & 3-12". Of course, this becomes more awkward as the number of individual issues increases. And if you're including the issue numbers, these would be strung out in the same respective order prior to the dates. Finally, if the listing spans more than one calendar year, then the volume number is also likely to change (but not with every issue).